# Ruby HTTP Request Throwing EOF Error

Tags: ruby, http, request

The following code block is throwing an EOF error but only for the specified domain:

```rb
require 'net/http'

uri = URI("https://api.discogs.com/database/search?q=wilco&token=mDwvoRKQSSGmKpvvxXLrABZXzFbiggcqhPHxUEXl")
response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
```

The error message I see is:

```
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/openssl/buffering.rb:182:in `sysread_nonblock': end of file reached (EOFError)
```

I am able to curl the request without a hitch. I have tried using HTTParty, open-uri, and different versions of Ruby. I have also attempted the solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244887/eoferror-end-of-file-reached-issue-with-nethttp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731936/http-request-keep-giving-me-eoferror) with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's working with [faraday library](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/)

```
require 'faraday'

url = 'https://api.discogs.com/database/search?q=wilco&token=mDwvoRKQSSGmKpvvxXLrABZXzFbiggcqhPHxUEXl'
response = Faraday.get url

puts response.body
```

Comment: It does indeed work. I was unfamiliar with Faraday. Excellent library. Thanks a bunch. I'm still unsure what was preventing net/http from working, but this got me over the hurdle I was in.

Comment: @Filipe It looks like low-level, deep library error.